# scrapy twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

Tags: python, scrapy

Trying to execute a scrapy spider inside a python script.
It's exactly what is defined by the scrapy doc, but doesn't work.

```py
import scrapy
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.settings import Settings

class MeteoJobSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "meteojobs"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.meteojob.com/jobsearch/offers?what=Architecte&where=Var%20(83)',
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        for result in response.css('.mj-offers-list li article'):
            date = result.css('.published-date::text').extract_first(),
            titre = result.css('.title::text').extract_first(),
            link = result.css('article::attr(data-url)').extract_first()
            idOffre = result.css('article::attr(data-id)').extract_first()
            infos = result.css('.list-unstyled h3::text').extract_first(),

            item = MeteojobItem()
            item["idOffre"] = idOffre
            item["date"] = date
            item["titre"] = titre
            item["infos"] = infos
            item["link"] = link
            yield item
settings = Settings({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'})
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)
d = runner.crawl(MeteoJobSpider)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 754, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

unwrapped, spider works well
What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're launching it as a python script (like `python meteojobs.py` f.e.)? You get this error if you try launching it in the typical way: `scrapy crawl meteojobs`

Comment: I'm so stupid. I was locked on scrapy and did not get out the framework. Many thanks

Comment: @nusibrains Would be nice, if you could explain more, write an answer and accept it.